# typescript missing file in node_modules\require_optional\

Tags: typescript, nuget-package, package.json

I'm working on a typescript project.

When I try to run it I got the following error message:

[image]

Its refer to node modules, but the compiler doesnt give error message.

- OPTION 1: I tried remove node_modules folder and package-lock.js and then "**npm install**" command it didnt help.
- OPTION 2: Then I tried the **nuget-package-updater**, the result was the same.

Here you can find the repo: https://github.com/BenceUszkai/crossfitnote

**Is there any other solution?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the repo is cloned, then the issue is unreproduceable.